# JPA is not saving reference to parent entity in manytoone and onetomany relation

Tags: java, spring, jpa, crud

How can i configure crud repository for having multiple entities?

I have entity Person and Numbe. Person has numbers, number have Person.

```
@Entity
public class Person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Number> numbers

    //getters and setters

}

@Entity
public class Number{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("owner_id")
    private Person owner;

            //getters and setters
}
```

And i have interface

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
public interface personIE extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
}

@EnableJpaRepositories
public interface numberIE extends CrudRepository<Number, Long> {
}
```

Now when i do this:

```
@Autowired
private personIE p_IE;

@Autowired
private numberIE n_IE;

public void test(){
  Person p = new Person();
  List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
  numbers.add(new Number());
  numbers.add(new Number());
  p.setNumbers(numbers)

  p_IE.save(p);

}
```

Now when i want to check what was saved, and retrieve data, i get only Person.
Its `numbers` property is always set to `[]`.The objects exists in database, however they are not being saved in the relation, why is that and how can i fix it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You sure you configured your entities correctly? It seems both have `@ManyToOne` relation or is it a typo ? Also in one to many relations I always make sure to set the parent of the child entity, meaning for each `Number` set `Person` field.

Comment: @dashboard thats typo thanks, the Person entity has OneToMany annotation

Comment: How about calling `numbers[i].setPerson(p)` for all `numbers`?

Comment: @dashboard that works, but thats not what i want to do...

Comment: I've encountered that problem once, it was mysteriously because of the child (Number) repository. How about you remove the `numberIE` and try again ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bidirectional relationship. So you need to set reference from both sides. For example:

```
public void test() {
    Person person = new Person();
    Number number1 = new Number();
    Number number2 = new Number();

    number1.setPerson(person);
    number2.setPerson(person);

    List<Number> numbers = person.getNumbers();
    numbers.add(number1);
    numbers.add(number2);

    p_IE.save(p);
}
```

Comment: but shouldnt cascade take care of this?

Comment: Cascading is for state transition from parent to its child entities. Hence the word `cascading`

Comment: @Dingo: what dashboard said is right and saving objects inside the collection does not mean its state changed.